# JSON for GSM Comm on STM32

Tags: stm32, c, digital-communications, gsm, tcp-ip

I am making a remote monitoring system using STM32F1 MCU in which there are few digital and analog sensors attached and I would send their readings to a remote server periodically. Can I use JSON string to send over GSM to the remote server?

I am using M95 GSM Module for TCP Socket connections. The data is over 3G connection.

Comment: It would be helpful to see a pictorial diagram of your setup and know what kind of GSM module you're using. As mentioned below, you can use almost any protocol for GSM data, but what kind of data are you talking about? Is it really 2G GSM or also UMTS, LTE data? That would make a world of difference regarding data quantities and rates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. Usually the cellular modules support both TCP and HTTP, so you can send any data you want. The connections are usually initiated and controlled via special AT commands over the UART.

Comment: I think TCP and HTTP are same things.. just the difference of which layer you are talking.

Comment: They are very different things. TCP carries application layer protocols, like HTTP and SMTP (e-mail). Depending how you design the server you can implement a custom protocol on top of TCP or use HTTP (and both of them can carry JSON payloads, though in slightly different ways).